# Starting an Activity from an Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I'm developing an app that downloads data from a server when a user makes a selection from a recycler view. I've got the data to download and parse in an Async Task in the Main Activity. This works fine but after the download is complete I want to start a new activity to display the downloaded data, this is where my problem is.

```
public GetItems(String username, Context context, Activity activity) {
    this.username = username;
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Above is the constructor for my Async Task. I'm passing these values from the `OnClicklistener` of my recyclerview.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    try {           
        //This is where the error lays
        activity.startActivity( new Intent(activity,BasketActivity.class));
    }        
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(tag,e.toString());
}
```

It's here where the problem lies, I've tried many different answers from similar questions but none of them have helped. Currently I'm getting the following error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,holder.basketName.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setBasketName(holder.basketName.getText().toString());
        MainActivity Activity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.new GetBasketItems(getUsername(),getImei(),getBasketName(),mContext,mActivity).execute();

    }
});
```

Above is my `OnClickListener` where I'm passing the values to the Async Task, I've tried using both context and activity and I'm getting a `NullPointerException` each time.

Comment: `MainActivity Activity = new MainActivity();` looks wrong if its an Activity

Comment: Activity activity = new MainActivity(); Declaring it this way gave me an java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference Error

Comment: you don't do  `new MainActivity();` if its an activity. why are you doing `mainActivity.new GetBasketItems(getUsername(),getImei(),getBasketName(),mContext,mActivity).execute();`

Comment: Best way to achieve this is via an interface. Pass the interface from the adapter and implement its method to the activity class.

Comment: @Demonic218 why do you want to start another activity? I mean, what you describe is pretty common, so I would face it this way: if your downloaded data is the same as your recyclerView items, simply refresh them. If different, one option would be to go on the new page immediately, and let the user to wait there for instance in front of a spinner. If neither of these suggestions work for you, then pass the activity.class string to the async task, and communicate the starting of the new activity with an intent, which is how in Android you start a new activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

activity.startActivity( new Intent(activity,BasketActivity.class));

to

```
 context .startActivity( new Intent(context,BasketActivity.class));
```

OR Create asynck task in adapter.

Comment: Should activity be MainActivity activity = new MainActivity(); ?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference - On this attempt

Comment: context.startActivity( new Intent(context,BasketActivity.class));

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is to use a callback and not passing the activity on the constructor.

You can simply create an Interface like:

```
 public interface OnNextActivityListener {
        public void nextActivityClickEvent();
    }
```

This callback should be an argument on your constructor Adapter and when you click on the itemView, it should look like:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       callback.nextActivityClickEvent();
    }
});
```

Inside your activity implement your interface:

```
public class YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnNextActivityListener {
....

//don't forget to add on your adapter constructor "this" as a parameter

   @Override
    public void nextActivityClickEvent(String url) {
        activity.startActivity( new Intent(YourActivity.this,BasketActivity.class)); 
    }
}
```

This is the best practice in order to handle actions inside adapters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Create an Interface like below:

```
public interface SuccessfulDownloadListener {
    void navigateToNewActivity(PfizerMessage message);
}
```

Implement the interface to your activity and create an object to this interface in your Activity class:

```
//declare the variable
private SuccessfulDownloadListener downloadListner;

//initialize the variable in onCreate()
downloadListner = new SuccessfulDownloadListener();

@Override
void navigateToNewActivity(PfizerMessage message){
    startActivity( new Intent(this, BasketActivity.class));
}
```

Pass this interface object to the Adapter constructor:

```
new RecyclerAdapter(..other parameters.., this)
```

your adapter would be

```
//declare the variable
private SuccessfulDownloadListener downloadListner;

//constructor
RecyclerAdapter(..other parameters.., SuccessfulDownloadListener downloadlistener){
    this.downloadListner = downloadListner;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    try {           
        //This is where the error lays
        downloadListner.navigateToNewActivity();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(tag,e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a null pointer exception because you're not supposed, in Android, to keep reference to activities, which could be destroyed by the system at any time.
To accomplish what you're trying, you should first read about [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and how to use it. Once understood, you would simply instantiate one and execute it from your MyActivity:

```
 new DownloadFilesTask().execute();
```

once executed, you would have the flow back to your in post execute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     nowShowDownloadedData();
 }
```

and the call *nowShowDownloadedData()* is back to your original activity, so at that point you can open the new activity in the usual way, passing this activity as the context.

Note: the async task is defined as private class within your caller activity, so it has access to it.

Comment: `private void ShowDownloadedData(){
        startActivity( new Intent(MainActivity.this,BasketOrderActivity.class));
    }` Trying this approach gives me a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Why when you create the new Intent(), you pass MainActivity.this? Try to pass this instead, as that code should be executed in the activity itself. Maybe worth to state this clearly: _nowShowDownloadedData()_ in my example should be a private method of MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add flag

```
Intent in=new Intent(context,NextActivity.class);
in.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(in);
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Intent intent=new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(),NewActivity.class);
holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Crete adapter to hold parsed data with getter and setter

```
public class DataAdapter implements Serializable { }
```

And add the data to the adpter

```
List<DataAdapter> adpter= new ArrayList<DataAdapter>();
adpter.add(new Thumbnail(name, mobile));
```

Pass the list to next activity using Bundle

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewClass.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("values", adpter);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Receive list in next activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
List<DataAdapter> Data = (List<DataAdapter>)bundle.getSerializable("values");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
public class MyAdapter extends Adapter {
     private Context context;

     public MyAdapter(Context context) {
      this.context = context;     
 }

 public View getView(...){
     View v;
     v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         void onClick() {
              Intent intent= new Intent(context, goto.class);
               intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               intent.putextra("your_extra","your_class_value");
             context.startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
     }
}
```